# Accessing a file inside a .jar file

Tags: java, file, resources, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file)

Starting to go completely bonkers over this after googling for hours. I've also seen variations of the question on the site but can't seem to get it working. A JFrame needs to read data from a ini file and I've created a method to open said file. Said file is stored in a folder called resources inside a jar file.

```
private BufferedReader openIniFile(String filename){
    BufferedReader brReader = null;                 
    try{
        File fileObj = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/" + filename).toURI()); // The fileobject of the file to read
        if(fileObj.exists())                                            
            brReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileObj));                     

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Exception while opening file: " + e.getMessage()); 

    }

    return null;
}
```

This of course works perfectly when I'm running the code after compilation, but throws an exception after being exported to a .jar file. I've looked into using InputStream, FileInputStream but can't seem to find a solution that would work.

How can I make the jar file recognize the resource?

Comment: I tried that, couldn't get it working :(

Comment: "couldn't get it working" doesn't help much

Comment: Sorry about that. It still throws a null exception.

Comment: ""couldn't get it working" doesn't help much" doesn't help much

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When your resourse is in JAR file, it's not a File anymore. A File is only a physical file on the filesystem.
Solution: use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). Something like this:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + filename)))
```

Comment: But if I use getResourceAsStream I can't use the File class right?

Comment: That's right. It's not a file.

Comment: I have a directory within resources which has all the files. How do I navigate through the directory to access all the files and then use above?

Comment: Simple and working solution: Make a jar which will include your assets or files and then assess it.

Answer (score 6):

You're reading the file wrong.  If the file is located in a JAR, you cannot use the `File` class.  Instead, you must get an `InputStream` to the file using `getResourceAsStream()`:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + filename);
```