# Accesing resources in a JAR

Tags: java, image, jar, javax.imageio

OK guys, so I'm trying to compile my game into a jar file, but I can't get the loading of images to work. When run from NetBeans, all is fine. But in the JAR, the URL is always null.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/textures/Lava.jpg");

    BufferedImage sourceImage = null;

    try
    {
        sourceImage = ImageIO.read(url);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I have tried unziping the JAR and checking the contents, my textures folder is there and the images inside also. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you should get the `URL` path as relative path of your system.

Answer (score 1):

Previously answered here:

[Accessing a file inside a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244/accessing-a-file-inside-a-jar-file)

Better use

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + filename)))
```

Comment: -1 Don't repeat an answer from another question. If it's a duplicate, **don't answer** and flag it.

Comment: @Duncan I also flagged the post and I know it will be removed soon but we should let author know that it's answered already.

Comment: If you flag, a comment appears and that's sufficient notification to the author. If you post an answer, it may attract down-votes because it appears like you are just harvesting reputation.

Comment: Okay. Sorry then, didn't know that :) Next time I'll just flag.