# How to create a file from classpath

Tags: java, file, classpath

I'm trying to create a new file in:

```
project/src/resources/image.jpg
```

as follows:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("src/image.jpg");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

but I get error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\project\dist\run560971012\project.jar!\image.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I'm trying to create a MultipartFile from it:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", file.getName(), "image/jpeg", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a file inside the .jar?

Comment: Do you want to read the file-contends of image.jpg or write it / create a new one? Please show the Line of Code where that Exception occurs.

Comment: if you have no subfolder `src` within your ressource-folder than you only need `/image.jpg`

Comment: I'm trying to create a MultipartFile from it

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the image data to the file!! You're trying to write an empty file in the path of the image!!

I would recommend our Apache friends [FileUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540942/how-to-get-the-path-of-running-java-program) library ([getting classpath as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540942/how-to-get-the-path-of-running-java-program)):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

URL url = getClass().getResource("src/image.jpg");
final File f = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, f);
```

This method downloads the `url`, and save it to file `f`.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that "image.jpg" is a resource of your project.
As such, it's embedded in the JAR file. you can see it in the exception message :

file:\D:\project\dist\run560971012\**project.jar!**\image.jpg

You cannot open a file within a JAR file as a regular file. 
To read this file, you must use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) (as detailed in this [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244/accessing-a-file-inside-a-jar-file)).

Good luck