# jmeter error on load SaveService.loadProperties();

Tags: java, jmeter

What I try to do:

I build a java service that load a testplan and run that one. I'm not using any Bash scripts and jmeter GUI. The java App is built as a service so that can run in the cloud. The Idea is, just to create some diameter Traffic data.

When I run the src on intellij (locally), all works fine.

Starting the app, all OK.

```
java -jar -Dserver.port=8090 diameter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Run REST request:

```
localhost:8090/api/v1/encode
```

after the request I get following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/myuser/Downloads/diameter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jmeter/bin/saveservice.properties (No such file or directory)
```

The first thing what I checked was jMeter Home.
system out on console:

```
HOME: file:/Users/myuser/Downloads/diameter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jmeter
```

The files are also available and located under bin, and slo in the class path.

```
/src/main/resources/jmeter/bin/saveservice.properties
/src/main/resources/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties
/src/main/resources/jmeter/bin/user.properties
```

I think the jMeter Home path is OK. ..or is that a wrong presumption?
Way jMeter can not load the saveservice.properties?

Is that because jmeter try to open the file with the FILE Class?
How can java load the saveservice.properties? or is that not necessary because jMeter Home is set?

```
private static final String jMeterHomePath = "/jmeter";
private static final String jMeterPropertiesFile = jMeterHomePath + "/bin/jmeter.properties";
...


File propertiesFile = FileStreamUtil.jMeterPropertiesToTempFile(jMeterPropertiesFile);
String jMeterPropertiesPath = propertiesFile.getPath();

StandardJMeterEngine jMeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(Encoder.class.getResource(jMeterHomePath).getPath());

JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jMeterPropertiesPath);

JMeterUtils.initLogging();
JMeterUtils.initLocale();

String home = JMeterUtils.getJMeterHome();
System.out.println("HOME: "+home);

SaveService.loadProperties();
```

Comment: Open your jar and check you have this resource :  `jmeter/bin/saveservice.properties` in a classpath dir or at the root of the jar

Comment: Actually, I've made it run to the cloud. [Last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863635/jmeter-error-on-load-saveservice-loadproperties#comment74851362_43867845)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [SaveService class source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/save/SaveService.java) `saveservice.properties` file is being read as follows:

```
// some code

private static final String SAVESERVICE_PROPERTIES_FILE = "/bin/saveservice.properties"; 

// Property name used to define file name
private static final String SAVESERVICE_PROPERTIES = "saveservice_properties"; // $NON-NLS-1$

// some more code


public static Properties loadProperties() throws IOException{
    Properties nameMap = new Properties();
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(JMeterUtils.getJMeterHome()
            + JMeterUtils.getPropDefault(SAVESERVICE_PROPERTIES, SAVESERVICE_PROPERTIES_FILE))){
        nameMap.load(fis);
    }
    return nameMap;
}
```

So you need to ensure you have `bin/saveservice.properties` file under your JMeter Home, this way it will work as expected.

If you are packaging JMeter into your solution you will need to [unpack it somewhere](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) in order to make it work. Otherwise you will need to patch the aforementioned SaveService class so it would read properties from resources file.

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on programmatic execution of JMeter test with some examples.

Comment: ok, to unpack some where in the cloud is not possible, we have no file service right now. The other point is way every where in the web I found java code with that call: JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jMeterPropertiesPath); That makes no sense because I not use the return value.

Comment: Well, you actually can specify custom *saveservice.properties* file location like `System.setProperty("saveservice_properties","/path/to/saveservice/properties");` however it will not be the end of the story as JMeter requires some more property files i.e. `upgrade.properties` and you won't be able to play this trick with it in such manner as JMeter adds an extra slash to it even if you override the property

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a file with File class when that file is within a Jar.
It can't handle the exclamation mark (!) in your file url.

If that's your problem, check for solution here:
[Accessing a file inside a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244/accessing-a-file-inside-a-jar-file)

Comment: No, thats not the problem I know how to get files from classPath. The point is that JMeter is build to use in file System environment. I get the solution now to run my service in the cloud. I move all prop files to temp folder from container and point JMeter home to this path.