# Audio file cant be found

Tags: java, audio, javax.sound.sampled

So for ActionListener practice Im trying to make a program that keeps track of how many times i die to this enemy in a video game. Each time the button on the GUI is pressed it increases the counter by 1 and it also is supposed to play a sound.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Main implements ActionListener {

    int bad = 0;

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static JLabel bText;
    private static JLabel damn;
    private static JButton button;
    private static Clip clip;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {

        File file = new File("noise.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);

        frame = new JFrame("times killed");
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        bText = new JLabel("Times killed:");
        bText.setBounds(150,130,120,25);
        panel.add(bText);

        damn = new JLabel("0");
        damn.setBounds(210,158,120,25);
        panel.add(damn);

        button = new JButton("Lmao you bad");
        button.setBounds(140,190,150,25);
        button.addActionListener(new Main());
        panel.add(button);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        clip.start();
        clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        bad++;
        damn.setText("" + bad);

    }
}
```

However when i run the program i get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: noise.wav (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.SunFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SunFileReader.java:117)
    at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1060)
    at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

The audio file is definitely in the source folder however and i need it there so when i make it into a jar file it brings the audio file with it.

[image: audio file in src folder]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a file inside a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244/accessing-a-file-inside-a-jar-file) Specifically, you can't use `new File("noise.wav");` to get a file/resource from inside a compiled jar, instead load it as a stream using `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("noise.wav");` and work with it that way.

Comment: Make the time to learn how to [Layout Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try moving the .wav file outside of the src folder, in the main project directory.