# Java classpath for my self contained MacOS java app does not work

Tags: java, macos, jogl, info.plist, .app

In a nutshell, the classpath that I'm setting in Info.plist does not seem to work. I continue to get an error saying that files within the jar files cannot be found.

Some context: I've created a self contained java app using the java jlink command. I've put the files for my java app within a MacOs App bundle. I modified the Info.plist to launch my main Java class. Which it does. The problem is that when I try to use some files that are in a jar file it cannot find them because it apparently cannot see the jar file.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong . I put the jar files in :

MakinaCraftApp.app/Contents/Resources/Java

I've even tried referencing the jar file directly with an absolute classpath but it still doesn't work. It is almost as if my MacOs app is prohibited from having access to jar files referenced by a classpath.

Is there some type of permission I do not know about? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

This is my Info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">

<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>bin/MakinaCraftApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>MachinaWJavaApp (1)1.0, Copyright {user} 2004. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>MachinaWJavaApp (1).icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>MakinaCraft</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MachinaWJavaApp2</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.1</string>
    <key>Java</key>
    <dict>
        <key>MainClass</key>
        <string>com.noatechnologies.machinawjava.MachinaWJavaApp</string>
        <key>StartOnMainThread</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Arguments</key>
        <array/>
        <key>ClassPath</key>
        <string>$JAVAROOT/gluegen_rt:$JAVAROOT/gluegen_rt_natives_macosx_universal:$JAVAROOT/jogl_all:$JAVAROOT/jogl_all_natives_macosx_universal:$JAVAROOT/jogamp_fat.jar</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

</plist>
```

One more thing, this is the exception I'm getting:

java.lang. Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jogamp.opengl. GLException: No shader code found (source nor binary) for src: [.. / ../shader/texture01 xxx.vp], bin: null at makinacraftmodule/com.noatechnologies.androidjavaapp.OpenGLAndroidApp.main(OpenGLAndroidApp.java:211) at makinacraftmodule/com.noatechnologies.machinawjava.MachinaWJavaApp.main(MachinaWJavaApp.java:203) at makinacraftmodule/com.noatechnologies.machinawjava.MachinaWJavaApp.main(MachinaWavaApp.¡ava:145) at makinacraftmodule/com.noatechnologies.machinawjava.MachinaWJavaApp.main(MachinaWJavaApp.java:111)

Caused by: java.lang. RuntimeException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: No shader code found (source nor binary) for src: [../ ../ shader/ texture01_xxx.vp], bin: null at jogamp.fat/com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.Threading|mpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading|mpl.java:201) at jogamp.fat/com.jogamp.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:202) at jogamp.fat/com.jogamp.opengI.Threading.irvoke(Threading.java:221) at jogamp.fat/com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:503) at makinacraftmodule/com.noatechnologies.androidjavaapp.OpenGLAndroidApp.main(OpenGLAndroidApp.java:185)

... 3 more

Caused by: com.jogamp.opengI.GLException: No shader code found (source nor binary) for sc: [. / ../ shader/ texture01 _xxx.vp], bin: null at jogamp.fat/com.jogamp.opengl.util.gIsI.ShaderCode.create(ShaderCode.java:551) at jogamp.fat/com.jogamp.opengl.util.g|sI.ShaderCode.create(ShaderCode.java:706) at jogamp.fat/com.jogamp.opengl.util.g|sI.ShaderCode.create(ShaderCode.java:771) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.macos.cgI.MacOSXCGLContext.createCALayerShader(MacOSXCGLContext.java:188) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.macosx.cgl.MacOSXCGLContext.access$4800(MacOSXCGLContext.java:84) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.macosx.cg|.MacOSXCGLContext$NSOpenGLImpl.associateDrawable(MacOSXCGLContext.java:946) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.macosx.cgl.MacOSXCGLContext.associateDrawable(MacOSXCGLContext.java:427) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.GLContextimpl.makeCurrent(GLContextimpl.java:740) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengI.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextlmpl.java:614) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1279) at jogamp.fat/jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147) at jogamp.fat/com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$12.run(GLCanvas.iava:1442) at java.desktop/java.awt.event. InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent. java:308) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventlmpl(EventQueue.java:773) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Access Controller.java:399)

at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.dolntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)

at java.desktop/java.awt. EventQueue.dis patchEvent(EventQueue java:742) at java. desktop/java.awt. EventDis patchThread. pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) at java. desktop /java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsEventDispatchThread.java:101) at java. desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: Really quite unclear. If the files you want to access are *inside* a jar file, that jar file should be in the classpath. The only one I see is *$JAVAROOT/jogamp_fat.jar*

Comment: Yes, the files I want to access are inside jogamp_fat.jar. I just confirmed that I can access class files just fine. It is files that are not class files where it is failing. Apparently this explains the reason for the failure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244/accessing-a-file-inside-a-jar-file

Comment: So those texture .vp files - are they in that jar or not after your packaging?

Comment: I'm hoping you're following something like [this](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling)