# Java compiler error: lookup table exceeds 65535 limit

Tags: java, lookup-tables

I'm running into this compiler error due to my extremely large lookup table based on this definition:

```
//92 X 182 array
private static final double[][] lookUpTable = new double[][]
{
    { numbers....}
};
```

As i understand it, dividing it up is a solution, but it would be extremely difficult to split this array up accurately.  I also believe i could move it out to a file, but i don't know if i could format it in a way to help me, plus i don't want file reads every second.
Are there any other suggestions to help me get around this?

Comment: I guess you refer to `Java lookup table exceeds 65535 limit` as compiler error. I wouldn't have understood this from your question, hadn't I run into the same rare error a few weeks ago --- My solution in the end was to read the values from a file at the start of the program once.

Comment: Yeah, it is related to the 65535 issue.  I struggle constantly with the ability to exactly describe my problem in a clear manner.

Comment: I edited the title to make it a bit clearer. Hopefully it draws more attention now.

Comment: thanks.  I'm out for the rest of the day, so i will check in tomorrow morning.  I am definitely leaning towards the resource file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your table to a file, embed the file as a resource, read it once in a static initialization block, and store it in a `lookUpTable` array. It will not be distinguishable from an array initialized through an aggregate, except there would be no 65535 limit. Storing in a static variable will help you avoid "reads every second".

As far as the format is concerned, you can put each row of the matrix in a separate line of the resource file. Reading and maintaining this file would be simple, because there would be no other mark-up around your numbers.

Here is a [link to an answer explaining how to read a file from a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403256/335858).

Comment: would it just be a standard txt file?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I would put the numbers in a plain txt file for maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file once on demand.

As you have a table/matrix, I suggest having one line per row. Read each line and split the numbers and parse them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the rows in a string (thus reducing the number of objects for java to handle)  as comma separated values, and on program start, split each row and so build up your table of longs.