# How to get a file from ressource

Tags: java

I know it seems like my question has been answered before, but I can't find an answer for my case.

What I am trying to do, is to get a File type from resource, so when it's packaged, it can be accessed. The answers I found were trying to read that file, but what I really need, is to construct a File object, because I have a third party library that is expecting that object.

Here is a the code I tried:

```
    String xslFilePath = new Test().getClass().getResource("/com/test/decision_template.xsl").getPath();
    System.out.println(xslFilePath);
    File xsltfile = new File(xslFilePath);
    System.out.println(xsltfile.getAbsolutePath()+", exist:"+xsltfile.exists());
```

I got this result:

```
    C:\>java -jar test.jar
    file:/C:/test.jar!/com/test/decision_template.xsl
    C:\\file:\C:\test.jar!\com\test\decision_template.xsl, exist:false
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\test.jar!\com\test\decision_template.xsl
    (Syntaxe du nom de fichier, de rÚpertoire ou de volume incorrecte)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:30)
```

I need a way to get that file so the .exists() return true.

Comment: This question already has many answers for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file. The most reasonable thing to do would be to not require a file, but just an `InputStream` in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the TrueZip library. It's quite good. I believe you'll need to implement your own DirectoryScanner or something.

Better yet, just knock up an implementation of your own which scans through all the jars on your classpath. [Here's an example](https://github.com/carlspring/web-xml-merger-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/carlspring/maven/web/xml/classpath/ClasspathScanner.java) of how I've done it in one of my projects on GitHub. I think that you could easily tailor it to suit your needs.

Have fun! :)