# Getting reources path creates weird path (in jar works)

Tags: java, jar, resources, jnlp

I've got some weird problem. I get access to my resources files like this:

```
File xmlFile = new File(getClass().getResource(xmlPath).getPath());
```

Where xmlPath is "/META-INF/file.xml".

When I run from Eclipse, everything works fine. Unfortunately, when I pack everything to jnlp file, upload with my web app on tomcat (from where I download all jar's by jnlp) it stops work.

When I run my jnlp, it downloads all jar's like it should and fails to start. Throwing this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\A050868\Desktop\http:\address:port\webapp\downloads\lib\package.jar!\META-INF\componentContext.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

How can I get access to my file, which is in resources/META-INF folder, in cached locale jar copy? For now it seems, like Java try get access to jar on server side - no this local, downloaded by jnlp.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You cannot treat opaque paths like normals paths.

Comment: I wanted to modify some configuration paths for client downloaded by jnlp. At the end I download them, save on client drive and then edit them in way I wanted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the files are `packed` together in your `jnlp` file. They don't to exist as individual files  on filesystem when you port your package.

That said, they are available on the `classpath`. You can access the `content` of your package using the appropriate `classloader`.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file?rq=1) may help you

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I figured out after few hours of searching. Finally I download content of this files, save on hard drive of client and then use them. No best solution, but works :)