# How to read/write in java to a file which is in NetBeans project itself

Tags: java, file, netbeans, file-io

I did search to find a solutions for this issue but I could not get proper ansewer.

My problem is I have a NetBeans project which has following folder structure.

### MyProject

```
      Source Packages
      ---------------
                     controller 
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     databaseconfiguration
                     application
                          Application.java
                     source
                          DbConfig.txt
```

DbConfig.txt is in source .
Application.java is in application

in Application.java I do read DbConfig.txt.
as following code

`String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("source/DbConfig.txt").getPath();`

```
File f = new File(path);
        fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while (br.ready()) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if(line.isEmpty()){
                continue;
            }
            else{
         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,line);
        }
```

}

this is working fine when I run in Netbeans IDE.

But after building , when I try to run this using MyProject.jar it gives null pointer exception (java -jar MyProject.jar  in cmd)

Please tell me how to sort out this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your file is in classpath, just use ClassLoader to return an InputStream for the resource instead of using it as a File ( you cannot read the resources from within the jar as simple Files)

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

More information here [How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file?rq=1)

Comment: Thanx for the answering .I am still getting the issue even I change the way you said.

Comment: can you post the update on the ticket with how and what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In the folder, from where you are running MyProject.jar, create another folder named "source" and in "source" place the file "DbConfig.txt"

Your directory should look something like this

```
../SomeFolder
--------------
              MyProject.jar
              .
              .
              .
              source
                    DbConfig.txt
```