# Jar classpath resources read failing which is triggerred from other executable jar

Tags: java, classpath

With reference to the link: [How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file/49069302#49069302)

I am trying using your code base and trying to read content of `sample.csv` which is residing in my project directory `src/main/resources`. I am unable to read the content, it says can not read file. Output:

> [Can not read file: `sample.csv`]

//This is added within your while loop after this check ***/* If it is a directory, then skip it. */***

I mean when file is detected then next is my below code snippet added to read the file content

```
if(entry.getName().contains("sample.csv")) {
   File f1 = new File("sample.csv");
   if(f1.canRead()) {
      List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(f1.toPath());
      System.out.println("Lines in file: "+lines.size());
   } else {
      System.out.println("Can not read file: "+entry.getName());
  }
}
```

Can anyone educate me what I am doing wrong here, how can I make it working?

**My requirement is this:**

1. (My micro-service) `Service.jar` imports `Parser.jar` library in its pom.xml
2. (My library) - `Parser.jar` has `FnmaUtils-3.2-fieldMapping.csv` file in `src/main/resources` directory
3. There is a `FnmaUtils` class that loads the `FnmaUtils-3.2-fieldMapping.csv` within its constructor, this class is part of `Parser.jar` - Here I am trying to read the content `FnmaUtils-3.2-fieldMapping.csv`, this step is keep failing with below error, tried all possible options shown in [[How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file/49069302#49069302])

   ```
   public FnmaUtils() {
      String mappingFileUrl = null;
      try {
          Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("FnmaUtils-3.2-fieldMapping.csv");
          mappingFileUrl = resource.getFile().getPath();
          loadFnmaTemplate(mappingFileUrl);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          LOGGER.error("Error loading fnma template file ", e);
      }
   }
   ```

**Getting error:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [`FnmaUtils-3.2-fieldMapping.csv`] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: `jar:file:/home/ravibeli/.m2/repository/com/xxx/mismo/util/fnma-parser32/2018.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/fnma-parser32-2018.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/FnmaUtils-3.2-fieldMapping.csv`
at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:218)
at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
at com.xxx.fnma.util.FannieMaeUtils.<init>(FannieMaeUtils.java:41)
at com.xxx.fnma.processor.FNMA32Processor.<init>(FNMA32Processor.java:54)
at com.xxx.fnma.processor.FNMA32Processor.<clinit>(FNMA32Processor.java:43)
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tryed to load the file through the classloader ?  For example this.getClass().getClassloader().getResource() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
>                                   .getResourceAsStream("SomeTextFile.txt");

Be sure the resource is in your classpath.

Comment: Yes Alex I tried that too. Still see the same issue

Comment: @ravibeli do you have classpath reference in the manifest file from Service.jar file to Parser.jar file ?

Comment: Can you open the jar file with 7zip or something manualy and verify the csv file is inside ?

Comment: Yes csv file exists in the Parser.jar, I extracted and verified in 7zip. Also verified the MANIFEST.MF file has an entry for the FnmaUtils-3.2-fieldMapping.csv as well, since I have added manifest entries in pom with <Class-Path>FnmaUtils-3.2-fieldMapping.csv</Class-Path>.