# JavaFX throws error for image after packaging

Tags: java, image, javafx

I have a JavaFX application which works perfectly fine in IntelliJ. But if I create an artifact and build it, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` due to it not finding a certain image. Below is the error message that I get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
        at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at gui.EditItem.generateLabel(EditItem.java:109)
        at gui.EditItem.lambda$start$1(EditItem.java:66)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at gui.EditItem.start(EditItem.java:65)
        at gui.Scene.launch(Scene.java:45)
        at gui.Item.editEntry(Item.java:88)
        ... 74 more
```

I know the error is due to this line (from line 109) as removing it fixes the issue:
`ImageView closeIcon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("../assets/baseline_close_black_18dp.png").toString()));`

I was wondering if anyone knows why I might be getting this error because if it works inside IntelliJ it should work after packaging it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using `..` is not supported by the `getResource` API.

Comment: Ok, I think that is the issue here. So is there no other way to go up a directory to get the asset other than the method explained by @thechaoticpanda below

Comment: The correct path starts at the classpath root and has a leading `/` in your case this indeed seems to be `/assets/...`. One thing that makes me scratch my head though is their use of classloader. The paths for classloader usually don't start with a leading `/`. I recommend not doing the `InputStream` handling yourself though. Let JavaFX take care of that and pass the URL; if the `InputStream` is available so is the URL: `new Image(getClass().getResource("/assets/baseline_close_black_18dp.png").toExternalForm())`

Comment: That also works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this solves your problem.

When running inside of intellij, you are accessing the image from the system path, as the image is present on the system, when you package, let us say to a jar, you will not be able to access the image using the system path.

So, make sure your image is getting packaged with the artifact that you are building and you'll need to alter your code to return you an `inputStream` as the `File` api is rendered useless in such a case, this would hopefully do the trick:

```java
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

        try {
                InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/assets/baseline_close_black_18dp.png");
                Image image = new Image(in);
                ImageView imageView= new ImageView(image);

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
```

Regards.

Some references backing up my answer:

[Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)

[Ref2](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/read-text-file-from-jar-file)

[Ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

For anyone looking through this later, as suggested by fabian, another option is to use `new Image(getClass().getResource("/assets/baseline_close_black_18dp.png").toExternalForm())` which will get the image from `src/assets/baseline_close_black_18dp.png`.