# How to publish an SBT project with resources included

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm developing a Scala tool under the SBT build system that depends on some resource files at runtime. The files are included in the normal `src/main/resources` directory. I successfully publish to my server and use it as a dependency in another project, but the files necessary for the tool to run are nowhere to be found!

`find . -name <necessary_resource>` within the project that depends on my tool finds nothing. It's clear then that `sbt publish` does not package up the resource files.

Is there a way to include the resources files whenever I publish the tool, or is there a different solution entirely to this problem?

Comment: The resource files are part of the JAR published. You have to assume they are in the classpath when reading them from code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file)

Comment: No, because the tool _requires_ that I be able to provide a path to the resource. It calls CLI tools that need to be able to use the resource as well.

Comment: Are the resource files separable from the `.jar`? Is there any way to reference them by name?

Comment: You'll need to extract the files from the JAR if your cli tool needs a file in the "regular" filesystem. If it's a java API it should be able to handle automatically path to a classpath resource.

Comment: That sounds hairy. It's not a java API. Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: I believe you'd need to share more details on the expected flow of execution. One solution could be that your program reads file from JAR and write it in a temporary file on disk and give this temporary file path to the CLI tool.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I'll do that. Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I'll give you a check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource files are part of the published JAR.

These resource files will be available in the classpath when usong the JAR as a dependency.

One solution could be to:

- read file from JAR/classpath (see [How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file))
- write it in a temporary file on disk
- give this temporary file path to the CLI tool